# System.out.println doesn't display anything when my Java GUI app is run as a Windows exe file

Tags: java, swing, exe, stdout

My Swing-based Java GUI application calls `System.out.println("foo");`.

It works as expected when I start the application in Eclipse IDE or from the command line using Gradle (`gradlew run`).

Any call to `System.out.println()` has no effect when it's running from the command line as a Windows exe file.

I'm using **Java 17** on **Windows 10**. The "released" exe version of the app is built using [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) that are set up by someone else in the organization so they're somewhat opaque to me, though I could go digging there if I had some direction.

I suspect there may be some configuration options that need to be set in the build process to allow `System.out.println()` to actually write to the `stdout` in the released exe version but I have no idea what they might be.

Any idea what could cause this behavior?

Comment: You would need to run the application from the console.  System.out.println print to the console.

Comment: In an organizational setting, why are your applications still using System.out's print methods? You should be using logging

Comment: What happens when you build a jar file and run *that* from the command line?

Comment: Perhaps exe uses javaw.exe which has no console, rather than java.exe which would output to the console. Hard to answer without knowing what your build does.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you understand that System.out targets to the console. If you want to debug through the print statement, better to use a JTextField and setting the value of "foo" rather. Or else you can use a file system as log.txt to use. If still you have some doubt please clarify with additional info. I will love to solve.